# Multiple country-specific stores - how to set up global products

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, best-practice, multicurrency

So I'm setting up a multi country/same domain store, with the stores living in /us/ and /au/

I want to have global products but localised prices. That is, I can build a product once that shows in both stores, but then have different pricing on each site.

Can anyone assist with the best practice to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Price has the scope capabilities of Website and Global (Same price across all websites).

To configure this to be website specific, goto:
`System > Configuration > Catalog > Price`

From there change the Catalog Price Scope value to Website and you'll be able to start using prices on each website independently from each other.

Comment: Thanks John. After setting that, and also setting Configuration > General > Currency Setup under the Website scope, I am able to get this working well. Thanks for your help.